# javascript treats string as an array of chars - how to change that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, char

In my project I'm downloading some data from external server - this data is in form of an array. Sometimes in this array there's only 1 value. For example:

[image: My array]

As you can see in this case I have an array, which consists of 5 arrays. The data that interests me is in `myArray[1][0]`. As you can see, there's only 1 value in this array and it is: "20161205022".

Now, since not always I'm getting only 1 value, I'm doing this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < myArray[1][0].length ; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[1][0][i]);
}
```

I'd expect to see "20161205022" in the console, but instead I see:

```
2
0
1
6
1
2
0
5
0
2
2
```

Why does it happen? The strange thing is that when `myArray[1][0]` has more values (for example: ["25", "35", "64", "58" ]) - they're interpreted correctly, not digit by digit.

Comment: So possibly you can have array or string in the outer array.?

Comment: can you post what you are getting when you are printing myArray[1][0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because JavaScript strings have a `length` property, and they support using `[]` to index into them.

You'll need to detect whether the source gave you a string or an array.<sup>1</sup> You could use `typeof`

```
if (typeof myArray[1][0] === "string") {
    // It's a string
} else {
    // It isn't
}
```

If you want to check further that you have an array in the "not" case, you could use the new(ish) `Array.isArray` (which is shimmable/polyfillable on older browsers).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or if you have any control over the source or ability to send feedback to those who are, fix the source / tell them to fix the source so it's consistent.

Comment: I'll check your solution on Monday. Unfortunately I can't look at this earlier. I'll give feedback when I test this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should Refer this example dude your problem will be solved...

```js
var myArray =new Array(5);
 myArray[1]= new Array(1);
  myArray[1][0]=20161205022;

  var div1 = document.getElementById('ht');
  function myfun(){
     for (var i = 0 ; i < myArray[1].length ; i++) {
       div1.innerHTML+=myArray[1][i]+"<hr>";
  }
  }

myfun();
```

```html
<div id="ht"></div>
```